# Image title not rendering in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm very basically using Rails 4.2.5 and Active Admin to handle some posts on my website. I'm using CKEditor to upload and manage Images in these posts which create urls to be embedded into the Post themselves. The issue that I'm having is that even though I'm saving the Post with the Image title hard coded, and when retrieving the post via the console, the image title is plain as day on the back end. It's just not rendering in the browser (Chrome/Safari/IE/FireFox) at all!

Post save action looks fine, this carries through server restart etc.

```
post.save
(0.2ms)  BEGIN PostAuthor Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "post_authors".* FROM "post_authors" WHERE "post_authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 59]] SQL (5.0ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "body" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "posts"."id" = $3  
[["body", "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\n<p>Hello<a href=\"https://www.secure-site-name-4.com/blog/5-javascript-books-you-should-add-to-your-reading-list\" rel=\"follow\">
# This seems like the important bit of the post to me...
<img title='5 best javascript books' alt=\"5-best-javascript-books\" data-rich-file-id=\"4471\" src=\"https://secure_site_name_4.s3.amazonaws.com/rich/rich_files/rich_files/1234/original/5-best-javascript-books.png\"></a></p>"
  ...
["updated_at", "2018-04-16 20:02:37.616437"], ["id", 993]] (0.8ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

However in my browser this renders with the alt, but without the title.

```
<img alt="5-best-javascript-books" src="https://secure_site_name_4.s3.amazonaws.com/rich/rich_files/rich_files/1234/original/5-best-javascript-books.png">
```

I found lots of information suggesting that the title won't show if the text is longer than the image width, or not at all if there's an alt. Editing these doesn't seem to be the case.

I'm straight up rendering it in my view with

```
= sanitize_field(post.body) # ruby slim
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: the code in the view is plainly

```
 = sanitize_field(post.body)
```

This is ruby slim and equates to

```
<%= sanitize_field(post.body) %>
```

Comment: Unlike the Microsoft Internet Explorer browser, Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, and other browsers do not display the text used in the alt attribute when hovering over an image. So change it to `<img alt="5-best-javascript-books"  title="5-best-javascript-books" src="https://secure_site_name_4.s3.amazonaws.com/rich/rich_files/rich_files/1234/original/5-best-javascript-books.png">`

Comment: Isn't that what's saved in the database though?
```<img title='5 best javascript books' alt=\"5-best-javascript-books\" data-rich-file-id=\"4471\" src=\"https://secure_site_name_4.s3.amazonaws.com/rich/rich_files/rich_files/1234/original/5-best-javascript-books.png\">"```
  ...

Comment: Is title working for you?

Comment: No that's the problem. It's saved in the database but not rendering in the view.

Comment: post the code you have in the view.

Comment: @amalrikmaia I tried to clarify the view for you. When I get home I can post the whole encasing div if that helps but it shouldn't make a difference. The post.body when viewed in the console is just a large text field where the image contains a title attribute.